# OleDb / OleDbConnection resizing form (bug?)

Tags: c#

Can someone help with a problem I can't seem to resolve.  I have created a C# form in both VSE2012 express for desktop and VSE2013 express for Desktop, where i have left the form the default size and added one button again totally default. The button is coded to open and close a db connection.

When the button is clicked the form and its contents all shrink by about 25%, i have tried all the default setting with no joy. I even substituted the access db file for a text file and it still happens.  Tried this on both window 7 and 8.1

Form1.cs (all the code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    + @"Data Source="
    + @"..\..\..\x.accdb");



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                myConn.Open();
                myConn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Uneditted Form1.Designer.cs

```
#region Windows Form Designer generated code

/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // button1
    // 
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(106, 138);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button1.Text = "button1";
    this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(282, 253);
    this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}

#endregion
```

Comment: can you provide Form1.Designer.cs?

Comment: Added it to the original post for you. It default created by VSE

Comment: Sorry, what? Forgive me for potentially asking something stupid, but is your *form* resizing when you click the button or is a new dialog box put on top of your form, containing an error message? Because that's what I'd expect. Not a resizing form.

Comment: My original program is much bigger but after finding the issue i cut it right back. So yes all the form code is posted.

Steps to recreate,
1. New C# application, 
2. add a button
3. add my code.    

........... 
When running the code, the form loads. Click the button and the form shrinks

Comment: Does the shrunken form have an "OK" button on it, by any chance?

Comment: just a bog standard button. The button literally just opens and closed a db connection.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `try`/`catch` block and just do `myConn.Open()`?

Comment: Can you show screenshots?

Comment: My guess is it's the `AutoScaleMode`.  Try setting it to `None` and see if the problem goes away,

Comment: AutoscaleMode does nothing. Removing try/catch does nothing.

 Uploaded a video to youtube. apologies for the shaky hands.

Comment: What is your Windows DPI setting?

Comment: http://youtu.be/zdby6gmbX_4

Comment: I find it very hard to believe the `OleDbConnection` is the cause. Does it work without? Do you have any IntelliPoint / Logitech mouse helpers installed?

Comment: Happens on PC and laptop. Has anyone tried it to see? No mouse helpers that i know of

Comment: Obviously `OleDbConnection` is irrelevant. It looks like some problem with DPI -- the form is scaled correctly on startup, but jumps to the lower DPI when the button is clicked. As to what could cause that, no clue (common control library mismatch? Assistive technology? Windows Update?), but it ain't a database connection.

Comment: I used the flowing to test for DPI and it reports 96 dpi onload and after button click

`float dpiX, dpiY;
            Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            dpiX = graphics.DpiX;
            dpiY = graphics.DpiY;

            label1.Text = dpiX.ToString() + " x " + dpiY.ToString();`

Comment: Just try to change the resolution of your screen from display settings. It worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

This must be a OleDb or .NET bug.   It is only noticeable on very high resolution screens and the simple act of calling OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open causes the form to ignore any DPI or Font scaling.

I've tried moving the call to open the OleDb to a separate class and also to a separate DLL but the results are always the same.

A user posted an example on YouTube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdby6gmbX_4

I guess we'll just need to report it to MS

***** Found a way to fix it

If you uninstall the "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" 32 bit version and then install the 64 bit version.  You then uninstall the 64 bit version and then reinstall the 32 bit version it will now work

Comment: I didn't think this would've worked but it did. Thanks a lot, you saved me!