# VB: form resized after datatable filled

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio, datagridview

I am new to VB. When button clicked, import excel data to DataGridView. But the entire form and DataGridView becomes smaller. Why?

Button click function:

```
Private Sub btImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btImport.Click
    txbStatus.Text = "Import data from excel..."
    'DataGridView1.DataSource = GetTable()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = excel_accerror.GetTable("C:\proj\test3.xlsx")
    'DataGridView1.DataSource = excel_accerror.GetTable2()
End Sub
```

'import data from excel

```
  Public Function GetTable(ByVal filepath As String) As System.Data.DataTable
        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
        Using MyConn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\pro\test3.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;") 'remove Xml, still works
            Try
                MyConn.Open()
                Dim da As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConn)
                da.Fill(dt)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function
```

Setting of DataGridView, and the entire form:

```
   Me.txbStatus = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.DataGridView1 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
    Me.btExport = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.btImport = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    CType(Me.DataGridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'txbStatus
    '
    Me.txbStatus.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12.0!)
    Me.txbStatus.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(14, 430)
    Me.txbStatus.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 4, 3, 4)
    Me.txbStatus.Name = "txbStatus"
    Me.txbStatus.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(488, 35)
    Me.txbStatus.TabIndex = 1
    '
    'DataGridView1
    '
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowDrop = True
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = True
    DataGridViewCellStyle2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
    DataGridViewCellStyle2.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.[False]
    Me.DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = DataGridViewCellStyle2
    Me.DataGridView1.Anchor = CType((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) _
        Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) _
        Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
    Me.DataGridView1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
    Me.DataGridView1.GridColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight
    Me.DataGridView1.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.NoControl
    Me.DataGridView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(527, 31)
    Me.DataGridView1.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
    Me.DataGridView1.Name = "DataGridView1"
    Me.DataGridView1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No
    Me.DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 31
    Me.DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 28
    Me.DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.[True]
    Me.DataGridView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(491, 519)
    Me.DataGridView1.TabIndex = 12
    '
    'btExport
    '
    Me.btExport.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(14, 516)
    Me.btExport.Name = "btExport"
    Me.btExport.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 53)
    Me.btExport.TabIndex = 13
    Me.btExport.Text = "Export"
    Me.btExport.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'btImport
    '
    Me.btImport.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(95, 516)
    Me.btImport.Name = "btImport"
    Me.btImport.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 53)
    Me.btImport.TabIndex = 14
    Me.btImport.Text = "Import"
    Me.btImport.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'frmDemo
    '
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1052, 580)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btImport)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btExport)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.DataGridView1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.txbStatus)
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    Me.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 4, 3, 4)
    Me.Name = "frmDemo"
    Me.SizeGripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Show
    Me.Text = "DEMO"
    CType(Me.DataGridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is a bug in System.Data.OleDb.

```
Using MyConn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\susu\usbproj\test3.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;") 'remove Xml, still works
    Try
        MyConn.Open()
        Dim da As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        MyConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Using
```

Uninstall my first Microsoft Access database engine 2010.
Then install the first one here https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Thanks to a similar but different post here:[OleDb / OleDbConnection resizing form (bug?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729854/oledb-oledbconnection-resizing-form-bug)